# Prolog: getting a list of atoms

Tags: prolog

I have a set of facts like this:

```
person(tj, 'Tom James', house).
person(jj, 'Jim Jones', hut).
person(aw, 'Alex Wolf', boat).
person(jw, 'John Wolf', boat).
```

And I want to get a list of places where they can live:

```
[boat, house, hut].
```

I tried setof:

```
placeList(Places) :- setof(Place, person(_, _, Place), Places).
```

But I only get each place at a time instead of a list. I also tried findall, but that would duplicate boat and it would not be in standard order. Can someone point out where I am going  wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `sort/2` on the result of `findall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must explicit quantification: add existential constraints to your variables

```
placeList(Places) :- setof(Place, K^N^person(K, N, Place), Places).
```